# Redux without action

Tags: reactjs, redux

i using React with Redux. i have two questions:
1.i do not use any action. is this bad pattern?
2. also when caling dispatch method, i send  object data with key index to reducer

```
 dispatch({
            type: 'SHOW',
            key: obj, // send obj object to reducer
          });
```

and through reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return {
        ...state,
        modalVisible: 'SHOW',
        dataItem: action.key,
      };
```

pass object data to listener component:

```
 const items = store.getState().schemaFormReducer.dataItem;
```

is my solution wrong? is there a better and more correct solution?

Compelete Code:

Reducer:

```
  function schemaFormReducer(state, action) {
      state = {
        modalVisible: 'Initial',
        dataItem: null,
      };
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SHOW':
          return {
            ...state,
            modalVisible: 'SHOW',
            dataItem: action.key,
          };
        case 'HIDE':
          return {
            ...state,
            modalVisible: 'HIDE',
            dataItem:null
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }

export default schemaFormReducer;
```

store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import historyReducer from './pims/reducers/historyReducer';
import schemaReducer from './pims/reducers/schemaReducer';
import schemaFormReducer from './pims/reducers/schemaFormReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    historyReducer,
    schemaReducer,
    schemaFormReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

component

```
const SchemaForm = ({ onModalShow }) => {

some codes...
....
....

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    schemaForm: state.schemaFormReducer.modalVisible,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onModalShow: obj => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SHOW',
        key: obj,
      });
    },
    onModalHide: () => {
      dispatch({
        state: 'HIDE',
      });
    },
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SchemaForm);
}
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Imagine that now in that component you have only two dispatches, what if you had 10, 20? You would have added a lot of lines over there in that file just to don't keep it separate ? Separation of concerns! Use it.

Answer (score 1):

In your action 'SHOW' name key for variable with data, doesn't matching with original redux code style, for this better use `payload: obj`.

In your root reducer you can use shorten names for different reducers:

```
constrootReducer = combineReducers({
history: historyReducer,
schema: schemaReducer,
schemaForm: schemaFormReducer,
});
```

In this case better use name type for first argument in your actions:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onModalShow: obj => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SHOW', 
        key: obj, //payload
      });
    },
    onModalHide: () => {
      dispatch({
        state: 'HIDE', //type
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Avoid use this:

```
const items = store.getState().schemaFormReducer.dataItem;
```

Your reducer should return only new state. Explain please, why do you need this string?

One more hint: try use useSelector, useDispatch, these features will help you simplify your mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps code, and do the same in a more readable way.

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: thank you for answer, therefore do not use action no problem?

Comment: i use this code `const items = store.getState().schemaFormReducer.dataItem;`  for  data  transfer beetween multiple pages and components